# Step count in best/worst case of a list search

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a list with the length "n" which is an unknown even number.
The probability of the existence of the key "x" in the cells with an even index is twice more than the others. for example:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_0_|_1_|_2_|_3_|_4_|_5_|    index

  |   |   |   |   |   |
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_9_|_5_|_7_|_3_|_8_|_0_|    value
```

since "x" surely exists the sum of all probabilities is 1. therefore each cell can have 1/length of probability; but according to the first line the distribution is different. thus:

```
p(T) = 1
p(0) + p(2) + p(4) = 2 * (p(1) + p(3) + p(5))
```

How can I calculate average comparison times?

Comment: I don't think the distribution of values has any effect on the best and worst cases of a linear search.

Comment: @molbdnilo the values don't; but the length of the list does. the more the items, the longer the exec time; not a linear relationship in this case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the probability that `x` is found on index `i` in your search:

[image: formula]

Comment: Thx, but I need the number of comparisons; I already have the probabilities.

Comment: @Nitwit that doesn't make any sense. You can't know the number of comparisons,  only probabilities.

Comment: I'm talking about the Best/worst/avg cases

Comment: @Nitwit first you need to be clear with your question. Second: best case: 1 comparison. worst case n comparisons. Average: can be computed only from probabilities :p

Comment: @nitwit I mean in the question post. The question itself must be clear. Comments are for requesting clarification and/or extra information and then the question needs to be edited to include those clarifications. In your question it's not clear what you are asking for.